# What is the meaning of this sentence, "I can't be with her without thinking she is cheating on me?

Tags: sentence-meaning

What is the meaning of this sentence:

> I can't be with her without thinking she is cheating on me?

My take is "every time I am with her, I am thinking she is cheating on me."

Is there a better version of it?

Comment: so both people are cheating?

Comment: Why does it change from one person to another in the middle of the sentence? It would be much more natural if it were the following: *I can't be with **him** without thinking **he** is cheating on me.* Or even this: *I can't see **him** with **her** without thinking **he** is cheating on me.* The current form might make sense with additional context—but you need to supply that. (It's the sudden introduction of *she* that's odd.)

Comment: Incidentally, I'm additionally confused by you first asking what the sentence means—and then asking if there is a better version of it. If you came across the sentence somewhere, please indicate its source. If you made it up, why would you do so without knowing what's being described?

Comment: @JasonBassfordSupportsMonica I am sorry. I just wrote "him" instead of "her". I read it in some book that I don't recall. can't I have an opinion in my head about a sentence and don't know if it is right or not? I just needed to see if my opinion is right and what is the better alternatives than my view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes "every time I am with him, I am thinking she is cheating on me" is also correct.

Its hard to say that there is a "better" way to say this. But I'll give some alternative wordings that mean the same thing.

> Thoughts of her infidelity riddle my mind whenever he draws near.
>
> His presence always makes me wonder if she is cheating on me.
>
> I can't be around him without thinking of the two of them together.

They all convey the idea that each time you are around him you think of their relationship.